# Query for getting strings in between CLOB field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a CLOB field in my table in Oracle DB where we store some text fields.
For eg. in the below text i  need to retrieve only 38001 when I query. The text will have many other fields also and the text will have the same line multiple times, but the query should avoid duplicates.

```
error 38001 error
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can someone help me with my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to retrieve only `38001` when I query, avoiding duplicates.

```
dbms_lob.substr(regexp_substr(column_name, 'error.*'), 10000, 1) AS error_message
```

Comment: This gets you only the error code with no duplicates?